# How to set iPhone Wallpaper Programmatically

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing an application in which I have to set image as the iPhone wallpaper (the background image on the "slide to unlock" screen).
Do we have any API reference for this.
Please help

Thanks in advance
Parmeswar

Comment: possible duplicate of [code to set image as wallpaper in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153003/code-to-set-image-as-wallpaper-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Not presently, the only thing that you can do is save the image to the camera roll and give the user instructions on how to change their wallpaper using the new image.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *str_mainMenu = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Unlock" ofType:@"jpg"];
    mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:str_mainMenu]];
```