# code to set image as wallpaper in iphone

Tags: iphone

please tell me the code for setting an image as wallpaper in iphone.

Comment: Please be specific... ?wallpaper in your app or iPhone screen wallpaper...

Comment: iPhone  screen wallpaper through my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible via code. You have to use the Settings.app

Comment: +1 Every time I see questions like this, I thank Apple for getting these things right. There's no reason an application needs to be able to mess with my wallpaper. I'll take care of that myself, thank you.