# Is that possible to set my iPad or iPhone wallpaper from my application..?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [code to set image as wallpaper in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153003/code-to-set-image-as-wallpaper-in-iphone)

I have been working on one of app and my client want to set wallpaper from app but i found that it's not possible.if anybody know how to set iPad wallpaper from application than please help me.

Comment: It's possible, but you'd need a jailbroken device and using private APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible for an app that needs to work without jail-breaking.