# How to set an image as wallpaper?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [code to set image as wallpaper in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153003/code-to-set-image-as-wallpaper-in-iphone)

I am creating an app in which i am having wallpaper sections. After the wallpapers displayed in full screen size there is button set as wallpaper when clicking on that button particular image should be set as iphone wallpaper.

Can anyone help me with this???

Answer (score 2):

There is no publicly available API to set the wallpaper. If there were, the App Store would be full of wallpaper setting apps.